# Django debug toolbar giving error about static file location

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

For the entire time I've been working on this project, I have had no problems with django debug toolbar, but suddenly, when I have it enabled, it gives me the error:  `The joined path (/images/user/blank-avatar.png) is located outside of the base path component (/opt/project/projectfiles/static)`.  When DJDT is disabled, I get absolutely no errors.

I'm not sure why this happens.  When I go into the shell and check what django.conf.settings.STATIC_ROOT is set to, it comes back with `/app/staticfiles`, which is correct.  I have no idea where this `/opt/project/projectfiles/static` is coming from.  When I do a search through the entire project, there is no place where `/opt`, or `opt/` shows up.

This project is in a docker container, and the project is completely stored in the /app directory.  I'm not married to DJDT, since I so rarely use it,  but I am concerned that this shows something I might be doing wrong.

Before anyone asks, this is not a media file.  It legitimately is in the static folder at /app/projectfiles/static/images/user/blank-avatar.jpg.  In production, it is stored on a digitalocean spaces container.

Apparently it is the `{{ staticfile.real_path }}` section in the following template code that finally raises the error:

```
  </ol>
{% else %}
  <p>{% trans "None" %}</p>
{% endif %}

<h4>{% blocktrans count staticfiles|length as staticfiles_count %}Static file{% plural %}Static files{% endblocktrans %}</h4>
{% if staticfiles %}
  <dl>
    {% for staticfile in staticfiles %}
      <dt><strong><a class="toggleTemplate" href="{{ staticfile.url }}">{{ staticfile }}</a></strong></dt>
      <dd><samp>{{ staticfile.real_path }}</samp></dd>
    {% endfor %}
  </dl>
{% else %}
  <p>{% trans "None" %}</p>
{% endif %}


{% for finder, payload in staticfiles_finders.items %}
  <h4>{{ finder }} ({% blocktrans count payload|length as payload_count %}{{ payload_count }} file{% plural %}{{ payload_count }} files{% endblocktrans %})</h4>
  <table>
```

Comment: Sorry, no.  I just disabled DJDT.  Like I said, I rarely use it anyway.  I just wanted to see if anyone had any answers as to what the problem might be.